# docker-compose File not found

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker and docker-compose files.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.15-alpine

## Add code
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies
COPY package.json package-lock.json /app/
RUN npm install

COPY . /app

RUN npm run build

# Start the main process.
CMD ["node", "dist/src/start.js"]
```

docker-compose,yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: ghcr.io/5e-bits/5e-database:latest
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'

  cache:
    image: redis:6.2.5
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'

  api:
    environment:
      MONGODB_URI: mongodb://db/5e-database
      REDIS_URL: redis://cache:6379
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - db
      - cache
```

When I try running `docker-compose pull` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1282, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1328, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1277, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1037, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/http/client.py", line 975, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 30, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 550, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 718, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1282, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1328, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1277, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1037, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/http/client.py", line 975, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 30, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version
    return self.version(api_version=False)["ApiVersion"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
    return self._result(self._get(url), json=True)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 237, in _get
    return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 600, in get
    return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 547, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('docker-compose==1.29.2', 'console_scripts', 'docker-compose')())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 81, in main
    command_func()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 200, in perform_command
    project = project_from_options('.', options)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 60, in project_from_options
    return get_project(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 152, in get_project
    client = get_client(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 41, in get_client
    client = docker_client(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
    client = APIClient(use_ssh_client=not use_paramiko_ssh, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
    self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 221, in _retrieve_server_version
    raise DockerException(
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
```

I'm not sure what is causing this issue. My operating system is fedora 37 and I installed both docker and docker-compose with dnf. Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Have you been able to fix this issue? I am having the same problem

Comment: @Javis Yes and no. I switched to a different linux distro since asking the question and now it works as expected. I can't reproduce the issue, but I don't think it's really solved.

Answer (score 4):

Is the Docker service running?

Try:

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently, basically my user didn't have enough permissions to run docker. I fixed it adding the user to the docker group.